# add-apt: command not found even after installing software-properties-common

Tags: debian

Even after doing in Debian 8 this command :

> apt-get install software-properties-common

[add-apt still can't be used](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mp71P.png)

Thanks by advance for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The command `add-apt` doesn't exist, you propably mean `apt-add-repository`.